# FAILED! => {"msg": "'item' is undefined"}

Tags: azure, loops, partitioning, disk

Trying to create a partition and mountpoint on the Azure Disks, which are getting attached to VM on creation as part of terraform. Disks should be created based on user input through Jenkins.
Each disk was passed with a `LUN number` and I am fetching the device name(sdc,sdd etc.) for each disk using that `LUN number` and `grep`. In `my_tasks.yml` this tasks to be looped with `include_tasks` in `playbook.yml` as below:

##### my_tasks.yml

```
---

- parted:
    device: "{{ volumename.stdout }}"
    number: 1
    state: present
- filesystem:
    fstype: xfs
    dev: "{{ volumename.stdout }}"
- mount:
    fstype: xfs
    opts: noatime
    src: "{{ volumename.stdout }}"
    path: "{{ item.mountpoint }}"
    state: mounted
- command: blkid -s UUID -o value {{ volumename.stdout }}
  register: volumename_disk

- blockinfile:
    path: /etc/fstab
    state: present
    block: |
      UUID={{ volumename_disk.stdout }}   {{ volumename.stdout }}      xfs defaults,noatime,nofail 0 0
```

##### playbook.yml

```
---
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  vars:
    mount: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/xyz/vars.txt') }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Generate the Lun_Name
      shell: "tree /dev/disk/azure/scsi1 | grep -i lun | awk '{print $2}'"
      register: lun

    - set_fact:
        lun_name: "{{ lun_name|default([]) + [ { 'name': lun.stdout } ] }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "LUN is: {{ lun_name }}"

    - name: Generate the Volume_Name
      shell: echo "$(ls -l /dev/disk/azure/scsi1 |grep  lun |egrep -o "([^\/]+$)")"
      register: volumename

    - set_fact:
        volumenames: "{{ volumenames|default([]) + [ { 'name': volumename.stdout } ] }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "VOLUMENAME is: {{ volumenames }}"

        #    - debug:
        #        msg: "the mountpoints are {{ mount }}"

    - set_fact:
        mountpoint: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/xyz/vars.txt').split(',')  }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "the mountpoints are {{ mountpoint }}"

        #     loop: "{{ mountpoint }}"
    - include_tasks:  my_tasks.yml
      loop: "{{ item.volumenames | list }} {{ item.mountpoint | list }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: "{{ item }}"
```

> fatal: [10.102.26.74]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'item' is undefined"}

Issue seems to be with loop inside a include_tasks, I'm able to get the loop working for mountpoint which is running after set_fact in playbook.yml

How can I resolve this issue or improve the code?

Comment: Can you identify which line is 21 column 3 to us?

Comment: I have restructured my code and now I am seeing a different error altogether, seems to me a some incorrect code for loops under include_task